# Spring initialization done outside the project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a java spring project . I see that one way of initialing the spring project is using this code in the main method.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Config.class);
        ctx.scan("com.example.db.app");
        ctx.refresh();
```

Is it possible to keep this outside a main method and then make a jar of this project. Add it as a dependency in pom.xml in other project and call the method which initializes the spring artifacts from there.

I tried doing it. I am getting an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemInformationRepositoryService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.example.db.app.service.ItemInformationRepositoryService.setItemInformationRepositoryService(com.example.db.app.repository.ItemInformationRepository); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.db.app.repository.ItemInformationRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: Can you add some code and elaborate the question? How did you try moving this out of the main method? Some code will be helpful

Comment: I just created a class and put all the initialization code in a method. Created an instance of the class and called the method.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message states:

> No qualifying bean of type [com.example.db.app.repository.ItemInformationRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

This means that the class `com.example.db.app.repository.ItemInformationRepository` is not in the Spring context. Perhaps you were expecting Spring to discover this class as a result of your instruction to Spring to scan `com.example.db.app`? According to the Javadocs for `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.scan()` ...

> Perform a scan within the specified base packages.
>
> @param basePackages the packages to check for annotated classes

So, in order for Spring to discover `com.example.db.app.repository.ItemInformationRepository` you must either:

- Annotate it with `org.springframework.stereotype.Component` so that it is discovered by `scan()`
- Register it in the same way as you are registering `Config.class` e.g. `ctx.register(ItemInformationRepository.class);`